# Echo text to a file owned by other user in a script

Tags: linux, bash

I am running a script as `vagrant` user (which is a sudoer) for setting up Postgres.
I need to update `pg_hba` file owned by `postgres` user.
The script requires accessing `$PGDATA` environment variable belonging only to `postgres` user, and not available in `vagrant` or `root` environment variable.

I tried below, but doesn't work.

```
echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5"  \
    |  sudo -c "tee -a $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf" - postgres > /dev/null
```

Output

```
[vagrant@metadb ~]$ echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5"  \
>     |  sudo -c "tee -a $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf" - postgres > /dev/null
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] [VAR=value] [-i|-s]
            [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-T timeout] [-u user] file ...
[vagrant@metadb ~]$
```

EDIT:
Meant to write `sudo su` in the question, in which -c option would be available.
Thanks to @roaima for hint on single quote to defer evaluation.

Below works as needed as described in the beginning paragraph.

```
echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5"      \
    |  sudo su -c 'tee -a $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf' - postgres > /dev/null
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" is close to useless. Next time, please consider answers to these questions. 1. What doesn't work? 2. What didn't happen that you expected to happen? 3. What happened that you didn't expect to happen? 4. What error messages did you receive? 5. What results do I get if search for those messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error message is telling you that you're using `sudo` wrongly. Specifically, there's no `-c` option. Have you looked at `man sudo` for the available options?
2. Even when you fix that your `$PGDATA` will be evaluated in the context of the caller (`vagrant`) because it's in a double-quoted string. You would need to put it in a single-quoted string to defer evaluation.
3. But then you'll find it's set to nothing because `sudo` doesn't (usually) set up any environment for the target user.

Try this

```
echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5"  |
    sudo -i -u postgres bash -c 'cat >>"$PGDATA/pg_hba.conf"'
```

Or, actually, you might as well just put the `echo` inside the `sudo` anyway:

```
sudo -i -u postgres bash -c 'echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5" >>"$PGDATA/pg_hba.conf"'
```

Comment: the first resulted in 
-bash: cat >>"/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf": No such file or directory

the second resulted in
-bash: echo "host    airflow         airflow         192.168.33.0/24         md5" >>"/var/lib/pgsql/12/data/pg_hba.conf": No such file or directory

Comment: My apologies @idazuwaika; that comes of my not testing the code I wrote. Fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Well here your issue is that the `-c` option is not a sudo one.

It also depends on how your `PGDATA` env var is defined in the postgres environment.

Assuming it is exported the `.bashrc` of postgres user, you may try with `... |sudo -u postgres bash -i -c 'tee -a $PGDATA/pg_hba.conf'`

(`bash -i` makes `.bashrc` to be read)

Comment: resulted in tee: /pg_hba.conf: Permission denied. It appears that $PGDATA is NOT evaluated in postgres user environment

Comment: It may also be that it is not defined when running with ``bash -i``... you can simply verify with the `-l` sudo option, which will display the command that would have been executed: if $PGDATA apprears, it was not resolved before being given to sudo.